# how can I debug go tests with gdb

Tags: go

I have some go tests. I would like to debug with gdb.

But the binaries built by `go test` are thrown away after running.

So how do I do it?

go 1.6 on windows/64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `go test -c` which will produce the executable file `xyz.test`. Afterwards you use `gdb xyz.test` to debug.

Just check `go test --help` for an explanation of the `-c` flag:

> Compile the test binary to pkg.test but do not run it
>   (where pkg is the last element of the package's import path).
>   The file name can be changed with the -o flag.